# Why isn't the innerHTML updating the page element after each iteration of the readyState property of the XMLHttpRequest object?

Tags: javascript

```js
function cback(text) { 
  alert(text)
}


function requestGET(url, req) { 
  var myrandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999)

  var callUrl = url + "?rand=" + myrandom;

  req.open("GET", callUrl, true)
  req.send(null)
}


function doAjax(url, callback) { 
  var myreq =  new XMLHttpRequest();
  document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = "Loading";

  myreq.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    
    if(myreq.readyState < 4) { 
      var plus = ".";
      document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML += plus;
      //alert(myreq.readyState)
     
    }  

    if(myreq.readyState == 4) { 
      var item = myreq.responseText;
      eval(callback + '(item)');
    }
  }

    requestGET(url, myreq)

}


document.getElementById("ajaxget").onclick = function() { 
  doAjax("libtest.php", "cback");
}
```

```html
<button id="ajaxget">Make a GET Call</button>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

So, this is roughly my code, which I had to edit a little bit to remove some unnecessary stuff, however,  I just noticed that for some reason, it's not working on here. The `readyState` only gets to state 1, and stops there. I am guessing this has to do with the fact that it's being run on *stackoverflow*..? Either way, you can see my code, and understanding what I'm trying to do.

I am trying to get the `innerHTML` to get updated with a `.` after each iteration of the `readyState` property. If you run an alert inside the `if(myreq.readyState < 4)` condition, with the `innerHTML` of the element, you will see that, it works as intended. With each iteration, a dot is added after `loading`, however, the actual element on the page adds only one dot, and then it stops until the `readyState == 4`, and the `callback` gets executed, only then all 3 dots appear at once.

First I was thinking that, perhaps the element on the HTML page doesn't update until the execution of all the functions is completed, but if that was the case, then why does the first dot appear?

I've also noticed that, when you add an alert inside the same condition, with the `readyState` property, the `loading` text does not appear on the page until `readyState` is 2. How come? The `loading` element is defined before the `if` condition, so why is it only showing at `readyState` 2, and not right after the function is triggered?

I know it's a bit convoluted question, but I hope you can understand what I mean. Please feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Whatever tutorial or book you're following, you should stop now. The code you have there is really obsolete. Passing function names as strings only to call `eval` on them, that's some hardcore 1999 stuff. Also, no, requesting `"libtest.php"` on stackoverflow will not magically load your own server's script :)

Comment: The reason for the error you're getting here is that you're only passing two arguments to your `doAjax` call, so inside the function, `callback` is undefined.

Comment: Do not use eval!

Comment: @ChrisG The book is actually from 2014. Probably the most recent one you can find. `Eval` is used to trigger the `callback` with the parsed `item`, which is in case `POST` request is made. I removed the `POST` from this example, because it's irrelevant. Also, I don't have a `libtest.php` server either. On my computer, it gives me the `not found` error too, but the rest of the code works as intended.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, I just realized I forgot to remove the other parameters. I just did, but it still doesn't work here on Stackoverflow. Either way. You understand what I'm trying to do, right? So, why is the innerHTML not getting updated with each iteration?

Comment: @epascarello Why? `Eval` is case the `item` is XML data. I just removed it from the example, so it probably doesn't make sense for that reason. Either way, could you try to answer my main question about innerHTML?

Comment: Here's a shortened and fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkz2ocj/ Also, the most recent JS book is from 2014? Lol

Comment: @ChrisG Your example is showing what I'm saying on my laptop. Can yo now try to address my main question? You click on the button, one "dot" appears next to "loading", and then the callback is triggered, and only when you close it, the rest of the dots appear. Why? Why is the innerHTML not updating with each iteration of the `readyState`?

Comment: @ChrisG Also, as I explained, `Eval` is used because there is another condition for XML data. `Eval` is there to parse the `item` in case it's XML.

Comment: eval is never the answer, there is always better solutions.

Comment: @epascarello such as..? and why is `eval` never the answer?

Comment: The stack snippet server cuts the request short, that's why readyState doesn't go through all four stages. Also, `eval`, which a lowercase `e`, is not needed at all to parse XML. `eval()` is a last resort, and only supposed to be used in case no alternative is available. If you don't really need it, don't use it, is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @ChrisG It does go through all the 3 states in my computer, and in your jsfiddle snippet! Put inside the condition an alert with the readyState property and you'll see. 

So, what should I use to parse XML then if `eval` is not to be used? And what's wrong with using `eval`?

Comment: @ChrisG I also forgot to ask something. In the above example, I am initiating the XMLHttprequest by saying `var myreq =  new XMLHttpRequest()`, however, in my book, this object is initiated differently. `var myreq =  getXMLHttpRequest()`. I Googled `getXMLHttpRequset()` but couldn't find any reference. Do you have any idea what is the difference? I had to change it with `new` instead, because stackoverflow kept producing an error.

Comment: It depends on the server response. The fiddle sends back a 404 error page, which is a valid response. Stackoverflow blocks the request, which cuts it short. Using `eval` is not wrong per se, but as I said, it's best used as a last resort. You don't need it at all here, so don't use it. If you want to know more about this just google "eval is evil".

Comment: As for the other point: `new XMLHttpRequest()` generates a new XMLHttpRequest object; this class is usually provided by the browser. However Microsoft's IE had their own version of this so you'd get an error if you used this. This lead to the very common workaround of implementing a custom function, in your case called `getXMLHttpRequest`, and check the browser inside. If the function detected it was called inside IE, it would return `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` instead. This was rectified in 2012, when Microsoft browsers started providing the `XMLHttpRequest` class.

Comment: And just for the sake of completeness: modern browsers have the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) now.